# Why does the data entered in multiple lines in a form(using ModelForm in django) appear as a single line in the database. How do I get rid of this?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-forms

[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE SAMPLE DATA I'VE WRITTEN IN THE FORMS (IN MULTIPLE LINES)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvQHF.png)

[CLICK HERE TO SEE THAT DATA IN THE DATABASE (WHICH HAS TURNED INTO A SINGLE THOUGH I'VE WRITTEN MULTIPLE LINES IN FORM)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrdXm.png)

This is forms.py where i have created my form using ModelForm

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from plagiarism_check.models import Files
class FilesCreate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Files
        exclude=()
        widgets={'firstfile':forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':50}),   'secondfile':forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':100})}
```

This is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.add,name ='add'),]
```

This is views.py

```
def add(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=FilesCreate(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request,'plagiarism_check/page1.html',{'form':FilesCreate()})
```

This is models.py

```
from django.db import model
class Files(models.Model):
    firstfile=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    secondfile=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstfile +' '+ self.secondfile
```

Comment: Could you please add what output are you expecting and what output you are getting?

Comment: Are you telling us you want to be able to add multiple records to the database from a single page? In that case you would need to use formsets.

Comment: I've added the screenshots of the input and output.@Nielsvh